# awk: Why the column saved in an array can not be printed out?

Tags: awk

Why the column saved in an array can not be printed out?

I have the following two files:

the first file is called "file1:"

```
a       1  
b       2  
c       3
```

the second file is called "file2":

```
1       100  
2       200  
3       300
```

When I run the following command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $0 "\t" a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

I only get the following output (basically I only get file1 printed):

```
a       1  
b       2  
c       3
```

What I expected output should be like:

```
a    1    100  
b    2    200  
c    3    300
```

I couldn't figure out why a[$1] was not printed out. Would you please help me? Thanks a lot!

Jeff

Comment: Print out `$1`, too: `print $0 "\t" $1 "\t" a[$1]`.

Comment: while reading file1: `$1` has values "a","b","c". But the keys into `a` are from file2 and they are "1","2","3". So `a["a"]` is empty.

Comment: @LarsFischer Thanks for your explanation. I always thought the array a is defined before in file2, and the key is still from file2. I will remember this.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks. I get the following output:                                                     a       1       a  
b       2       b  
c       3       c                     so, from Lars Fischer's answer, I understand the key $1 is from file1 even the array a is defined based on file2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the wrong key, so the array element is empty for that key

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
             {print $0, a[$2]}' file2 file1
```

or if the keys are already sorted as in your example,

```
join -12 -21 file1 file2 -o1.1,1.2,2.2
```